# How to check string contains a string in msbuild?

Tags: msbuild, vcxproj

I have a problem writing a `targets` file for my `vcxproj` project.
In my `targets` file the first thing I want to set some build properties based on the configuration so I have this:

```
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('Debug', StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))">
      <PropertyGroup>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
```

But when I try to open the project with imported target file I get an error

```
error  : The expression ""Debug".Contains(Debug, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)" cannot be evaluated. Method 'System.String.Contains' not found.
```

I am using Visual Studio 2022 Preview.
Acording to [MSBuild docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2019) the string is just a .Net5 string and should have the method.
Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That overload of `Contains` is only available in recent .Net versions, not in e.g. [4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8) so that is why it is not found. Workaround: convert to lower then compare

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition="$(Configuration.ToLowerInvariant().Contains('debug'))">
  </When>
</Choose>
```

Comment: I don't understand the static methods. I am able to use `<When Condition="$(Configuration.IndexOf('Debug', 0, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) != -1">` for example. I just think `Contains` is nicer than `IndexOf`...

Comment: Sorry my mistake, didn't look carefully. Edited my answer with correct information: it's just that your version of MSbuild doesn't have that overload, I guess, because I don't think it is actually built against .Net 5 or similar?

Comment: That seems weird. I would assume Visual Studio 2022 Preview uses the most recent version but maybe not. I don't know much about .Net and how much new .Net 5 is. I guess you are right if no one has ever make it work with the `Contains`.

Comment: VS 2022 might use the most recent version of .Net to build your own projects, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the version of .Net used to build msbuild itself is the same.